# I can't addpeer in a private chain, why?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript, peers

There are 2 nodes(10.0.50.90, 10.0.50.91), and they can ping each other well.
There are geth in every node and their genesis json file is same.Then I run geth in evey node. In 90's geth console:

```
> admin.nodeInfo.enode

"enode://22417b070ba9e8558ef37acc4fa9818735509ff23c0608cdc03d78c7ff3670fad5277806f35343f7dfe7b58eec7f5faafecc10384af26195ac469ea3dcc535ff@[::]:30303"
```

In 91's geth console:

```
> admin.nodeInfo.enode
"enode://f08d120a6edbb0f4f4859fc480c7377cf78593e71ad1de2f9a7b92f04f5d97fffa9e065224e93b2142f4489f649720a84b6de5f496e8c12bf98bc6aaf0883e3e@[::]:30303"
```

then I add 91 in 90's geth console here:

```
> admin.addPeer("enode://f08d120a6edbb0f4f4859fc480c7377cf78593e71ad1de2f9a7b92f04f5d97fffa9e065224e93b2142f4489f649720a84b6de5f496e8c12bf98bc6aaf0883e3e@10.0.50.91:30303")
true
> admin.peers
[]
> admin.peers
[]
> admin.peers
[]
> admin.peers
[]
> admin.peers
[]
> admin.peers
[{
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "182cf8aaadbe949e9dada0874a990f86fe61043738164757ca1d4c007a81585dfee0d517e4211000fc06034de2c42cdfef90c8b020f4fdabb4abd97d0d81a8cd",
    name: "Geth/azureNode/v1.6.1-stable-021c3c28/linux-amd64/go1.8.1",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.0.50.90:49936",
      remoteAddress: "13.90.198.214:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: "handshake"
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "9067508301728d7ad21871e38d71a2b2949b9f924d4358569b213b27f8a97119a02d490639c0f97a2445191ec78df64e2fd08f0a9479895711d24416884485e8",
    name: "Geth/v3.3.0-1-gdd95f05/linux/go1.7",
    network: {
      localAddress: "10.0.50.90:42046",
      remoteAddress: "46.101.153.17:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: "handshake"
    }
}]
```

so you can be clear from above that when I type  admin.peers the first few times, it shows [], but it shows something at the end.But there is no 91's information in the result.
So I can't addpeer in a private chain, why? and why it can show some remote nodes I didn't add before at the last time?(is it the auto discovery mechanism' function?) 
how to add 91's node when I type admin.peers it can show 91's information?
Many thanks.